# how to merge 2 data records to one in a recyclerView ? (mysql & volley)

Tags: android

I want to merge two data records to become one based on the same `DAY`, but different `"Sesi"` such as `Sesi 1`, and `Sesi 2` being 1 in a `recyclerVCiew`

please see my application [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2Z32.png)

here I use `mySql` with `volley` [JSON + Inner Join MYSQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fS5KA.png)

**Main Activity**:

```
 StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_ALL_JADWAL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        //converting the string to json array object
                        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);

                        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jadwal = array.getJSONObject(i);
                            String kelas = jadwal.getString("Kelas");

                                    if (kelas.equals(Kelas)) {

                                        jadwalHarianList.add(new JadwalHarian(
                                                jadwal.getString("Nama_Pengajar"),
                                                jadwal.getString("Mata_Kuliah"),
                                                jadwal.getString("Ruang"),
                                                jadwal.getInt("Sesi"),
                                                jadwal.getString("Hari"),
                                                jadwal.getString("Jam")
                                        ));
                                    }
                                    JadwalRV jadwalRV = new JadwalRV(getApplicationContext(), jadwalHarianList);
                                    recyclerView.setAdapter(jadwalRV);
                                    jadwalRV.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });

    //adding our stringrequest to queue

    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(stringRequest);
```

**JadwalRV Adapter**:

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(JadwalRV.MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int i) {
    JadwalHarian jadwalHarian = mJadwalHarian.get(i);



        myViewHolder.tHari.setText(jadwalHarian.getHari());
        myViewHolder.tIsi.setText("Waktu\n" +
                "Ruang\n" +
                "Mata Kuliah\n" +
                "Dosen Pengajar");
        myViewHolder.thjam.setText(
                "= " + jadwalHarian.getJam()+
                        "\n= " + jadwalHarian.getRuang() +
                        "\n= " + jadwalHarian.getMata_Kuliah() +
                        "\n= " + jadwalHarian.getNama_Pengajar() );

        // SESI 2

    myViewHolder.tIsi2.setText("Waktu\n" +
            "Ruang\n" +
            "Mata Kuliah\n" +
            "Dosen Pengajar");
    myViewHolder.thjam2.setText(
            "= " + jadwalHarian.getJam()+
                    "\n= " + jadwalHarian.getRuang() +
                    "\n= " + jadwalHarian.getMata_Kuliah() +
                    "\n= " + jadwalHarian.getNama_Pengajar() );




}
```

Here is [Structure Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIuvk.png) which I used `inner join` in my PHP json

Comment: you mean you want overwrite ?

Comment: yes it can be like that, I want to combine the data

Comment: please post your 3 tables structure

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIuvk.png , sir

Comment: A little bit confusing here. From the  image you provided https://i.stack.imgur.com/fS5KA.png, the json already succesfully retrieved ? Is it the output from  your php script?

Comment: yes it can be retrieved, I have deleted it to recyclerview. please see https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2Z32.png

Comment: remove the code for SESI 2, what will you get ?

Comment: the result is the same but not duplicate

Comment: @Ronny, You are always getting  `Sesi 1` and  `Sesi 2` or it can be 3 or more??

Comment: see sir , I hope to get output like this :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zdX5.png

Comment: @Ronny, You are having a parameter `kelas`, Who's are having their values as I can see in response `R28` and `Sesi 1` and `Sesi 2` are having same with `kelas` as `R28`. You can combine into one position by getting `kelas` and It's are having `R28` with `Sesi 1` and `2` respectively and this is how you can show `Sesi 1` and `2` in same position data on `RecyclerView`

Comment: @RakeshKumar can you help me how is the method ? I have been quite confused with this problem :-(

Comment: @Ronny, You can fetch the data and combine into one like I mentioned above or you can store the data into database with kelas and can fetch accordingly

Answer (score 0):

**You can try like this following not obvious, but It can help you:**

```
try
        {
            JSONArray array = new JSONArray();

            ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> jadwalHarianList = new ArrayList<>();

            JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();
            try
            {
                jsonObject.put("Kelas", "R28");
                jsonObject.put("Sesi", "1");
                jsonObject.put("Mata_Kuliah", "Pemprograman #1");

                array.put(jsonObject);

                jsonObject = new JSONObject();

                jsonObject.put("Kelas", "R28");
                jsonObject.put("Sesi", "2");
                jsonObject.put("Mata_Kuliah", "Algoritma #2");

                array.put(jsonObject);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("ldfjdlfj","data----111_jsonOb_ex>>>"+e);
            }

            Log.e("ldfjdlfj","data----2222>>>"+array);


            String previous = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jadwal = array.getJSONObject(i);
                String kelas = jadwal.getString("Kelas");
                String Sesi = jadwal.getString("Sesi");
                String Mata_Kuliah = jadwal.getString("Mata_Kuliah");



                if(kelas.equalsIgnoreCase(previous))
                {
                    HashMap<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();

                    map.put("kelas",array.getJSONObject(i-1).getString("Kelas"));
                    map.put("Sesi",array.getJSONObject(i-1).getString("Sesi"));
                    map.put("Sesi2",Sesi);
                    map.put("Mata_Kuliah",Mata_Kuliah);

                    jadwalHarianList.add(map);
                }
                else
                {
                    previous = kelas;

                    HashMap<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();

                    map.put("kelas",array.getJSONObject(i).getString("Kelas"));
                    map.put("Sesi",array.getJSONObject(i).getString("Sesi"));
                    map.put("Sesi2","");
                    map.put("Mata_Kuliah",Mata_Kuliah);

                    jadwalHarianList.add(map);
                }



        }

            Log.e("ldfjdlfj","data----333_>>>"+jadwalHarianList);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: beforehand i really understood thank you, but sorry sir i don't understand this method :(

Comment: and why is the manual "programming # 1" and "Algorithm # 2" written in the code? isn't it automatically taken from json sir?

Comment: @Ronny, I had written manually so that you can understand how you have to put the data into your `ArrayList`, just give you logic